# crystal reports group and show only 1 record but sum other records

Tags: sql, visual-studio, t-sql, crystal-reports

I have a grouped column that is a string . The column keeps repeating. I only want it to be displayed once per group and sum the remaining columns based on .

Database table structure:

```
-personame-id-salary-
```

I want to group by personname (display once) and sum salary.

**The output in cystal right now**

```
jon  10,000
jon  10,000
bob  50,000
bob  50,000
greg 10,000
greg 10,000
```

**It should be:**

```
jon 10,000
bob  50,000
greg 10,000
```

i am only grouping by personame.

Here is my group selection code: **(None fix the above problem:)**

groupName #1({table.personname}) = NthLargest(1,{table.personname});

OR

{table.personname} = NthLargest(1,{table.personname},{table.id});

OR

{table.personname} = Minimum({table.personname});

Comment: If you want to sum by salary, shouldn't the values be 20,000, 100,000 and 20,000 respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though you are currently displaying id and salary in the detail section (or possibly the group header *and* group footer).

You need to suppress the detail section, and display the id and the **sum** of the salary in the group footer.

If you need to add the id and/or the sum of the salary to the group footer, simply drag and drop them from where they are currently displayed in the report.

To suppress the detail section, right-click in the grey area to the left of the page layout in the design tab for the Details section and select Suppress (No Drill-Down). (You should also do the same for the group header section.)